# What is the right way to use go-ini's mapTo function?

Tags: pointers, go, reflection

### Background

I'm trying to use go-fed's [apcore](https://github.com/go-fed/apcore/) framework to build a federated app. I have implemented the `apcore.Application` interface but I'm stuck during the loading of the configuration.

The server responds with `panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Type on zero Value` when trying to map the configuration loaded from `config.ini` to the `apcore` configuration struct.

This happens [here](https://github.com/go-fed/apcore/blob/master/config.go#L148):

```golang
func loadConfigFile(filename string, a Application, debug bool) (c *config, err error) {
    InfoLogger.Infof("Loading config file: %s", filename)
    var cfg *ini.File
    cfg, err = ini.Load(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    err = cfg.MapTo(c)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
.
.
.
```

where it clearly just uses an uninitialized `*config` pointer. This led me to believe this has nothing to do with the code I've written (an implementation of `Application`) which has not been yet used here.

### The question

I decided to write a very simple usecase of `MapTo` to check if it works as I expect it to:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/ini.v1"
)

type Config struct {
    Name      string `ini:"NAME"`
    Male      bool
    Age       int `comment:"Author's age"`
    GPA       float64
}

func main() {
    var cfg *ini.File
    var err error
    cfg, err = ini.Load("config.ini")
    var c *Config
    // c := &Config{ Name: "test", Male: true, Age: 13, GPA: 4.5 }
    // c := new(Config)
    fmt.Println(c);
    err = cfg.MapTo(c)
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

This also returns `panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Type on zero Value`. Neither passing a `Config` literal works (it then complains that it `cannot map to non-pointer struct`), nor an initialized pointer (`signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation`).

This is the [function declaration](https://github.com/go-ini/ini/blob/master/struct.go#L226)

```
func (s *Section) mapTo(val reflect.Value, isStrict bool) error {
```

### What does it require as input and why does the apcore framework use it this way if it fails?

(I also tried with older go-ini just in case it's a recent bug)

Answer (score 1):

`var c *Config` provide you a nil pointer of type `*Config` which cause dereferencing panic.

Do instead

```
var foo Config
c := &foo //which give you a non-nil pointer to zero struct
err = cfg.MapTo(c)
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this results in `signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1`